# JPQL validation error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

If I don't write a custom query the `@Autowired` `FirstnameRepository` object is `null`, therefore I tried to write a custom query, but this produces the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List FirstnameRepository.findByNation(Nation)!
```

Since the query looks correct to me, I think it has something to do with my classstructure or incorrect annotations.

**FirstnameRepo**

```
 public interface FirstnameRepository extends JpaRepository<Firstname, String>{

    @Query("SELECT fn FROM Firstname fn WHERE fn.nation = :nation")
    List<Firstname> findByNation(@Param("nation")Nation nation);
}
```

**Firstname Model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Firstnames")
public class Firstname extends Name implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "gender")
    private short gender;
    @JoinColumn(name = "nation", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Nation nation;

    public Firstname() {}      
}
```

Since there is also a `Lastname` model class I extend a class named `Name` to save `Firstname` and `Lastname` in the same `Map`. `Name` has no table in the database and both classes only inherit the ID property.

**Name class**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Name {
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

If I comment the `findByNation()` method out, the server starts without a problem. I hope this is all you need, the server configuration is more or less copied from a working project, but if I should include something let me know. thanks

**EDIT
The Problem was a incorrect configuration. I changed alot of stuff before testing it again, but seems like the main issue was a wrong version of  in the web.xml.**

Comment: should'nt it be `SELECT fn FROM Firstname fn WHERE fn.nation in :nation`, ie `in` operator for collection

Comment: It is one specific nation in Firstname, it's the "One" side of the relationship, therefore I don't think so. But I will try it. => Same error.

Comment: This propably won't help with your issue, but shouldn't Name class be Serializable as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though this problem has most likely something to do with the Query itself, in my case was a configuration issue. Here are some things I checked

- Version of  in web.xml which specifies the Version of the used Servlet specification - [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985378/what-exactly-is-the-web-app-version-what-does-it-affect)
- Make sure your database context (e.g. db-context.xml) gets loaded

Answer (score 0):

Your query is malformed... you can't put this "`fn.nation = :nation`" where Nation is an Entity, you should use a join between tables to work fine.

I suggest you this [link](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query).

Comment: I thought about that, but I generated some Modelclasses in Netbeans and it creates Queries like this "SELECT f FROM Firstname f WHERE f.nation.region = :region". In this case Region is also an Entity and there is no join for nation either. But I will try it with a JOIN.

Comment: @KenavR Let me know, if does not works fine, I try to help you in another way.

Comment: No difference. I tried it with Objectcomparison and Id comparison, I guess the error doesn't have anything to do with the Query itself. I will check my configuration again.

Comment: @KenavR see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733877/jpql-join-queries), more or less is the same error. But in any case check your configuration.

Comment: It was indeed a configuration issue, my web.xml had the wrong <web-app version> and I also changed some other stuff.